# Jquery loading hide when image is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jquery that catch link url (this link is an image) and simple show this image.
My problem is the loading. I want to show LOADING and hide it when the image is completely loaded. but I can't because my new image has no class and I don't not how to check if it is done.

How can I show and hide this loading properly?

js

```
$(function() {
    $(".p").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var element = $(this);
        var I = element.attr("href");

        $("#loading").show(); //SHOW LOADING

        $("#imgfull").empty();
        var img = $("<img/>").attr("src", I); // add new image
        $("#imgfull").append(img); // add new image

        $('#???').load(function(){
             //$("#loading").hide();    //hide loading?????
        })

    });

});
```

html

```
<a href="http://ilikewall.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/3d_wallpapers_hd.jpg" class="p">click to load</a>

<div id="loading">LOADING</div>
<div id="imgfull"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4g0n8asc/

thank you

Comment: You should not use hide, makes things slow ...

Comment: what is the best one to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
img.load(function(){
    $("#loading").hide();
})
```

Example :: http://jsfiddle.net/Frogmouth/4g0n8asc/2/

**NOTE:**

`.load()` method on `<img />` sometimes has some problem, this little plugin fix all (or a lot of) these issues:
[imagesloaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded)

Comment: ;) take a look to the **note**.